# State pressed not working in a button

Tags: android, button

I have a button in my activity on which I want the following behaviour

The button should have a selected color border
When the button is pressed, that selected color should fill the whole button

For eg if I choose orange, the button should have a default orange background and when the button is pressed, the button should be filled with orange.

So I made this custom drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

I applied this as my background to the button and I got the default behavior right. But when the button is pressed, I observe no change.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put two property `android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"` then it will work like `and(&)` operator. Correct way is to set individual `<item/>` for all behaviour

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```